# How many cyclic permutations can be shaped by two sets of 3 different points

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let's say we have a set $M=\{v_{a}, v_{b}, v_{c}\}$ of three **different** points and another set $N=\{u_{x}, u_{y}, u_{z}\}$ of three different points. Let's also assume that a cyclic permutation $C_6$ (circle with 6 points) can be created by those points with the restriction that consecutive points must belong to different sets.

For example:$$C_6' = \{v_{a},u_{x},v_{c},u_{y},v_{b},u_{z}\}$$
In other words an $m$ point must be succeded by an $n$ point and vice versa. Of course every point of the two sets can be used only once.

How do we prove mathematically that there can only be created 6 circles by the sets above?

**Note**: A cyclic permutation $C_6$ is defined by the **order** of the elements. That is to say, all permutations will be consisted of the same 6 points but the points will be ordered in a different way for every permutation.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If all 6 points lie on the same circle $C_6$, then any set of 3 points will reproduce the same circle $C_6$.

Comment: @sammygerbil - I believe they are talking about a cyclic set of $6$ elements, not an actual circle. i.e., an ordered sequence where cyclic permultations are consided equivalent to the original.

Comment: How may ways are there of arranging the $6$ elements in a line with $v_{m1}$ always in position $1$, and the other two elements of $M$ in positions $3$ and $5$?

Comment: @sammygerbil Paul is right. That's what I meant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Not necessarily. I am actually asking about the permutations of arranging those discrete elements with the restriction mentioned above.

Comment: @sammygerbil  Please note that a circle $C_6$ is defined by the order of the elements.

Comment: @johngonidelis Circles and points are terms in geometry. If you mean cyclic permutations and elements then you ought to change the words used in your question and title to make it clear what you are asking. Clarifications should not be left in the comments as these are not always checked and can be deleted.

Comment: @sammygerbil fixed

Comment: You must put the $v_m$'s in alternate spots, and since you are modding out by circular symmetry, any valid arrangement is equivalent to one with $v_1$ at the top and $v_2$ at 4:00 and $v_3$ at 8:00. Now you have $6$ ways to put the other three elements at 2, 6, and 10:00, each of which gives a different (bidirectional) circular arrangement. Also, label the points $x,y,z$ and $a,b,c$ -- double subscripts just make it hard to read and type.

Comment: @Ned I just fixed the changes your proposed. Could you please post your solution as an answer and in that case could you elaborate more on your methodology?

Comment: May I point out that if you had done the calculation I indicated, you would have gotten the exact same answer as you accepted from Ned. This is not a coincidence. You might want to look into why it works for the future.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry I thought you were asking for some clarification question. Please post an elaborate answer so I could check wether it is more comprehensible and accept it over Ned's maybe.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Your suggested calculation though comes up to be sth like: $6$ ways for all the $N$ elements $*$  $2$ combinations for positions $3$ and $5$. That's $12$ combinations.

Comment: I should have looked closer at Ned's solution. Mine disagrees with him over whether flipping is allowed. Which is intended is something you will have to decide. My idea is that you place the remaining elements relative to the position of $v_{m1}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Why is it that your solution takes the flipping cases as different ones?

Comment: Because I don't interpret the problem as meaning $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the same cyclic arrangement as $\{6,5,4,3,2,1\}$. Ned does. Whoever gave you this problem is the arbiter of which of us is correct. You will have to clarify it with them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks! I think that your case is correct.

Comment: Ned's interpretation is not flawed, but simply from experience, it is likely not the one intended.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I 'd accept the answer if you posted one.

Comment: Leave it with Ned. Even if his flipping is not intended (and again, you should ask whoever gave you the problem about that), it is an easy adjustment of multiplying by 2 to get my answer, and the rest of the answer is the same reasoning.

Comment: Just to weigh in here, I agree that the original wording more likely suggests only rotations and not reflections -- however, the OP asked for why the answer is $6$ -- which implies that reflections should be included, that's why I answered that way, not from the original wording 

Comment: @Ned You were both very helpful. One who reads the post will get what's going on, nevertheless. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just call the two sets of points $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$ which must alternate around the circle. Given any valid arrangement, you can rotate it so that $a$ is at clock position 12:00 and then, by flipping if necessary, have $b$ at 4:00 and $c$ at 8:00 (I interpret the problem as meaning all $12$ rotations and reflections of the hexagon are to be considered the same arrangement).

Now having placed $a,b,c$ in those positions, you can assign $x,y,z$ to 2:00, 6:00, and 10:00 arbitrarily, which gives $3! = 6$ ways to do it -- and each of these $6$ is a unique arrangement, even with all the symmetries.

That's it, for an intuitive argument. You could do a full Burnside's Lemma thing on this, but is unnecessary here, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is, I don't understand how does that cover the cases were $a, b, c$ are not in that order. To be more clear: does that cover the case of $a, m_{element}, c, m_{element}, b, m_{element}$ ?

Comment: Actually, Burnside's lemma is almost trivial here, now that I think about it, since only the identity symmetry fixes any assignments. There are $6*2*6$ assignments before the symmetries, so the number of orbits will be $(1*72+0+...+0)/12 = 6$.

Comment: @johngonidelis yes, by flipping the circle over (again, that's how i interpret the problem, mainly because otherwise the answer is $12$, not $6$).

Comment: wow! Didn't thought about the flipping. That must be the detail I was missing. That and the professor's lack of mathematical formalism. Thank you very much.